# ¿Por qué razón cuando intento imprimir una variable se imprime su dirección en memoria y no su valor?

Tags: python, lista, objeto

Teniendo el siguiente código:

```
class Usuarios:
    def __init__(self,nombre,genero,edad):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.genero = genero
        self.edad = edad
        
    def funcion(self):
        list = []
        if self.genero == "Femenino":

            list.append(Objeto)

            print("Femenino\n", list)

        elif self.genero == "Masculino":

            list.append(Objeto)
            print("Masculino\n", list)

        else:
            print("Ha ocurrido un error")
```

Estoy intentando añadir el valor del objeto en texto a la lista, en este caso `("Juan", "Masculino", "30")`.

```
Objeto = Usuarios("Juan", "Masculino", "30")
Objeto.funcion()
```

Cuando ejecuto el código imprime la ubicación del objeto, por lo que no sé si estoy agregando alguna información a la lista

Gracias.

Comment: Siendo específicos: ¿Que estás intentando añadir a lista?

Comment: Hola, Le estoy asignando al objeto los datos del usuario, la función debería comparar por el genero y agregarlo a la lista y dependiendo del genero imprimir un mensaje ej: masculino y los datos que almaceno en la lista. Pero al imprimir la lista imprime es su ubicación y yo quiero ver es el contenido de la lista (si es que guardo la información o no, si esta bien el código o no). se que puedo hacerlo imprimiendo las propiedades de la clase únicamente. Pero estoy aprendiendo a utilizar clases. Gracias por comentar

Comment: Ok, checa mi respuesta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### ¿En Python, qué es un objeto?

En Python todo son objetos, hasta los tipos de datos nativos son objetos. Estos cuentas con atributos y métodos implementados. Cuando se está generando un objeto a través de la instancia de una clase, se puede decir que se está definiendo un tipo de dato personalizado.

Este objeto tiene un comportamiento predefinido, con la definición de sus atributos y métodos que hacen uso de sus atributos. Esto al igual que todos los elementos del programa, requiere de espacio en memoria.

La diferencia de los tipos de datos nativos y este tipo de dato personalizado, es que los primeros cuentan con una representación formal en el lenguaje.

Un objeto definido, no cuenta con la representación oficial de una expresión valida de Python.

### ¿Qué hace a un objeto tener esta representación formal?

Veamos dos métodos mágicos, que se pueden definir en la definición de una clase:

### [`object.__str__()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types)

Según su referencia en la documentación:

> > Called by str(object) and the built-in functions format() and print() to compute the “informal” or nicely printable string representation of an object. The return value must be a string object.
>
> > This method differs from object.**repr**() in that there is no expectation that **str**() return a valid Python expression: a more convenient or concise representation can be used

Traduciendo el segundo parrafo:

> Este método es distinto a `__repr__()`, debido a que no se espera que el método `__str__` devuelva una expresión válida en Python.

Esto significa que

- El método es llamado cuando se usa el objeto como argumento en las funciones `format()`,`print()` y `str()`.
- Define una representación informal para representar el valor del objeto como string

Esto se puede verificar definiendo `__str__()` en un clase:

```
class Clase:
    def __init__(self,atributo):
        self.atributo = atributo

    def __str__(self):
        return "Objeto con el atributo {}".format(self.atributo)
```

Si se usa intenta hacer un conversión de string con un objeto generado por esta clase, ya sea con `print()`, `format()` o `str()`. Esta conversión va tener como resultado el valor retornado por `__str__()`.

```
Objeto = Clase("foo")
print("Valor del objeto:",Objeto)
```

mostraría

```
Valor del objeto: Objeto con el atributo foo
```

*¿Por que se dice que esto es una representación informal?*

Debido a que esta representación solo es válida a la hora realizar una coversión a string. Si se intentara representar de otra manera se obtendría esa "dirección en memoria", que en realidad es la descripción prredeterminada.

```
lista_de_objetos = [Objeto]
print(lista_de_objetos)
```

mostraría

```
[<__main__.Clase object at 0x000001FC65AE60D0>]
```

El método `__str__()` no define la representación formal de un objeto.

### [`object.__repr__()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types)

Según su referencia en la documentación:

> > Called by the repr() built-in function to compute the “official” string representation of an object. If at all possible, this should look like a valid Python expression that could be used to recreate an object with the same value (given an appropriate environment).
>
> > If this is not possible, a string of the form `<...some useful description...>` should be returned. The return value must be a string object. If a class defines **repr**() but not **str**(), then **repr**() is also used when an “informal” string representation of instances of that class is required.

Traduciendo un fragmento del primer parrafo:

> Se llama la función `repr()` para definir la representación "oficial" de un objeto. Si es posible debería de lucir como una expresión válida de Python.

Traduciendo un fragmento del segundo parrafo:

> Si no es posible, se representará con un string en la forma `<... información útil ...>`

*¿Que hace la función `repr()`?*

Retorna la representación formal de un objeto en formato de string, cuando se dice objeto se habla de variables, valores retornados por funciones, etc...

```
variable = "Mango"
print(repr(variable))
```

mostaría

```
'Mango'
```

Ahora, si se define el método `__repr__()` en una clase, se puede definir cuál va a ser esta salida.

```
class Clase:
    def __init__(self,atributo):
        self.atributo = atributo

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Soy un {}".format(self.atributo)
```

Siguiendo las indicaciones de la especificación en la documentación:

> The return value must be a string object.

Ahora el objeto no solo es representado a la hora de usarse como string:

```
objeto_mango = Clase("Mango")
print(objeto_mango)
```

mostraría:

```
Soy un Mango
```

Cualquier representación es válida:

```
lista_objetos = [objeto_mango]
print(lista_objetos)
```

mostraría:

```
[Soy un Mango]
```

Esto es lo que se considera como una *representación formal*.

> ¿Por qué razón cuando intento imprimir una variable se imprime su dirección en memoria y no su valor?

Es debido a que cuando intentas imprimir la lista que contiene el objeto, este objeto no cuenta con una representación formal si no con la representación predeterminada o bien "la dirección de memoria".

### ¿Por qué no es válida la recursión en diferentes ámbitos dentro del método de una clase?

> Cuando ejecuto el código imprime la ubicación del objeto

Hay otro errores en tu código

Veamos la expresión

```
list.append(Objeto)
```

Esto implica añadir a una lista dentro del propio objeto al objeto.

```
Objeto => contiene => |list_ = [Objeto]|
```

**Nota:*** Aquí se cambia el nombre de `list` por `list_`, debido a que `list` es una palabra reservada del lenguaje y esto puede generar problemas.

```
Objeto => contiene => |list_ = [Objeto]|
```

Se está instanciando un objeto como parte del mismo objeto, esto sería válido si se hiciera de la manera adecuada.

Por que no se está definiendo un un nuevo objeto que forme parte de otro objeto de la misma clase, si no que el mismo objeto esta definido con un objeto.

> No se puede definir algo con algo, ya que algo no está definido.

*¿Cuál es la manera adecuada de instanciar objetos dentro de otro objeto con la misma clase?*

Generando un objeto **nuevo**

```
self.list_.append(Usuarios(self.nombre,self.genero,self.edad))
```

### Explicación

Cuando se crea un objeto como este

```
usuario1 = Usuarios("Juan", "Masculino", "30")
```

Los parámetros pasán a `__init__()`y pasan a instanciarse como atributos de la clase. Esto permite que los métodos de dicha clase tengan acceso nativo a estos parámetros. Al generarse una nuevo objeto con los atributos de la clase, se está generando un objeto con los mismo parámetros que se inicializó la clase.

```
objeto = Clase(arg0, arg1) #Objeto inicial
                ^      ^
                |      |
                *      *
                __init__(self,arg0,arg1)
                               ^     ^
                               |     |
                               *     *
                               funcion() => Clase(arg0,arg1) #Objeto nuevo
```

El objeto inicial, puede almacenar otro objeto **distinto a este mismo**.

Hablando de ámbitos, es necesario instancia a `list_` como atributo de la clase. De esta manera tiene ámbito global implícito sobre todos los métodos de esta misma clase, y valor perdura en el objeto que se inicialize

```
self.list_ = []
```

### Representado el objeto formalmente y viendo la lista

> por lo que no sé si estoy agregando alguna información a la lista

Al definir la representación del objeto, podemos visualizar este objeto y ver si se está agregando información a `list_`

```
def __repr__(self):
        return "Objeto: ({}, {}, {})".format(self.nombre,self.genero,self.edad)
```

Al invocar el método de la clase `funcion()` y imprimir el valor actual de del objeto generado

```
usuario1 = Usuarios("Juan", "Masculino", "30")
usuario1.funcion()
print(usuario1)
```

Podemos ver que sí, **el objeto está en la lista!**

```
Masculino
 [Objeto: (Juan, Masculino, 30)]
Objeto: (Juan, Masculino, 30)
```

Espero todo te haya quedado claro.

Answer (score 1):

No se si esto es lo que quieres:

```
class Usuarios:

    def __init__(self, nombre, genero, edad):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.genero = genero
        self.edad = edad
        
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Usuarios(nombre={}, genero={}, edad={})".format(self.nombre, self.genero, self.edad)

    
Objeto = Usuarios("Juan", "Masculino", "30")
print(Objeto)
```

Cuando imprimes un objeto, por defecto te retorna la dirección de memoria donde ha sido instanciado por la clase. Sin embargo, existen los metodos "**str**" y "**str**" que son invocados cuando consultas una variable o cuando la imprimes. Si no se define el método "**str**", el método "**repr**" toma el control de ambas acciones. Asi que ahora cuando imprimas un objeto se mostrará la cadena generada en el método "**repr**".

Cuando en consola escribes (considerando que hay un objeto instanciado llamado "obj"):

```
ojb <ENTER>
```

Se invoca a `__repr__`

Cuando en consola escribes:

```
print(obj) <ENTER>
```

Comment: Cual seria la diferencia entre usar repr o str??