# ¿Cómo contar caracteres repetidos de un Entry en Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, interfaz-gráfica

Estoy haciendo un programa que reciba una dirección de correo electrónico a través de un `Entry` y al pulsar un botón muestre en consola la cantidad de arrobas que hay en dicha cadena, pero escriba lo que escriba, me dice que hay 0 arrobas.

Este es el código Python:

```
from tkinter import Tk, StringVar, Entry, Button

root = Tk()

texto = StringVar()
texto.set("")

def comprobador():
    global texto
    texto_str = str(texto)
cantidad_arrobas = texto_str.count('@')
print("hay {} arrobas escritos".format(cantidad_arrobas))

texto_input = Entry(root, textvariable=texto)
texto_input.grid(row=0)
boton_comprobar = Button(root, text="comprobar", command=comprobador)
boton_comprobar.grid(row=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existe un error en el indentado de tu código, creo que este ha sido un descuido al pegar el código dentro de la publicación, sin embargo el error principal que haría no funcionar tu programa es la línea.

```
texto_str = str(texto)
```

Esta línea no estaría regresando el contenido del widget Entry, para conseguir el contenido del widget debes llamar el método `get`.

```
from tkinter import Tk, StringVar, Entry, Button


def imprimir_repeticiones():
    global texto
    texto_str = texto.get()
    cantidad_arrobas = texto_str.count('@')
    print("hay {} arrobas escritos".format(cantidad_arrobas))


# UI configuration
root = Tk()

texto = StringVar()
texto_input = Entry(root, textvariable=texto)
texto_input.grid(row=0)

boton_comprobar = Button(root, text="comprobar", command=imprimir_repeticiones)
boton_comprobar.grid(row=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Algunas notas adicionales al problema principal serían que evitaras usar variables globales, y particularmente en este caso no haría falta hacer uso de `global texto` dentro de la función debido a que no existe asignación de un valor a la variable global, únicamente se esta accediendo a su valor. Por lo anterior y ajustando algunos otros pequeños detalles, te recomendaría que le dieras un ojo a las siguientes modificaciones.

```
from tkinter import Tk, StringVar, Entry, Button


def imprimir_repeticiones(texto, texto_buscado):
    cantidad = texto.count(texto_buscado)
    print(f"Existen {cantidad} cantidad de {texto_buscado} en {texto}")


# UI configuration
root = Tk()

texto = StringVar()
texto_input = Entry(root, textvariable=texto)
texto_input.grid(row=0)

boton_comprobar = Button(root, text="comprobar", command=lambda: imprimir_repeticiones(texto.get(), '@'))
boton_comprobar.grid(row=1)

root.mainloop()
```

No es mucha la diferencia pero creo que es un buen consejo que puedes tomar en cuenta para tus próximas experiencias.

Answer (score 0):

> escriba lo que escriba, me dice que hay 0 arrobas.

El problema surge en la linea

```
texto_str = str(texto)
```

La variable `texto` originalmente era un objeto, al castearlo a string no obtienes el contenido del `Entry`. Lo que realmente obtienes es la representación de este.

```
class Clase:
    def __init__(self,texto):
        self.texto = texto

objeto = Clase("corre@servicio.dominio")
string = str(objeto)
print(objeto)
```

Este programa mostraría `<__main__.Clase object at 0x00000166A9C680D0>`, **no hay arrobas.** El texto ingresado en el `Entry` es un atributo de este objeto, cuando lo casteas a string no obtienes ese atributo, si no su **representación** (tal vez te interese leer [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/375810/por-qu%C3%A9-raz%C3%B3n-cuando-intento-imprimir-una-variable-se-imprime-su-direcci%C3%B3n-en-m/375921#375921)).

Por la tanto `string.count("@")` devolvería 0, debido a que en la respresentación del objeto no hay ningún arroba. Nunca hagas casting tan brusco a objetos `Entry`, en su lugar usa el método [`.get()`](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm).

### ¿Cómo solucionarlo?

Pienso que te estás complicando mucho,

Si quieres obtener la cuenta de un caracter en un `Entry` no es necesario definir un `StringVar()`, cualquier `Entry` ya tiene predefinido el método `get()`. También es innecesario definir una función para esto, cuando puedes hacer el `print()` en el mismo `command` del botón.

```
entrada = tk.Entry(root)
entrada.pack()

boton_comprobar = tk.Button(text = "Comprobar",command = lambda: print(entrada.get().count("@")))
boton_comprobar.pack()
```

Si lo que quieres es mostrar por pantalla la cantidad de arrobas por cada modificación al `Entry`, lo más aconsejable es usar el evento [`trace()`](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) con el modo de escritura en el `Entry`. Esta vez si hay que hacer uso de un `StringVar()`

```
string = tk.StringVar()
entrada = tk.Entry(root,textvariable = string)
string.trace("w",lambda a,b,c,string = string:print(string.get().count("@")))
entrada.pack()
```

Espero haberte ayudado.